# Excel: Checksum-like function to check if table copied correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have the following scenario:

1. I have a spreadsheet A with a large table.
2. I open spreadsheet B and copy the table from A into it.
3. I want to check if I copied the table from A to B correctly.

In order to do step 3 I usually sum (and average, etc.) all the numbers in the table check if I get the same number as I get for the original table.

However, I would like to have a checksum function like `checksum(<2D RANGE>)` which would return a checksum (e.g. MD5) of the table in the given range. I would use this checkusum function in spreadsheet A and then in spreadsheet B and compare the obtained values to find out if the table I copied matches the original one.

Comment: Not sure if this covers the 2-D range, but its a start: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3498356/657668

Answer (score 1):

You could piece together something with worksheet functions that pairwise compares the values in your source and target tables and then returns `TRUE` if the values match and `FALSE` if not.

For example, the following compares `A1:Z100` on Sheet1 and Sheet2.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*EXACT(Sheet1!A1:Z100,Sheet2!A1:Z100))=ROWS(A1:Z100)*COLUMNS(A1:Z100)
```

This does a pairwise case-sensitive comparison of the cells in each range and counts the number of matches. This count is then compared to the number of cells in the rectangular range. If the counts match, then `TRUE`. Otherwise, `FALSE`.

Note that this only compares the values in the cells. This does not check formulas, only their output.